# Unable to access data from .env file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest

I am trying to write automation scripts for get request. 
As part of the request i need to send secure key in headers. I am giving following details in test

```
url = "some url"
headers = {"key":"12345"}
response = requests.post(url, json_request, headers=headers)
```

At the moment i'm exposing header details. I am trying to get them saved to environ.env file and import them into config file. But i have no luck.

```
environ.env file
test_headers = {"key":"12345"}

config file
import os
headers = {"headers": os.environ.get("test_headers")}
```

Unable to get the code working. Headers are not recognised while executing code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Got this to be working

```
environ.env file

KEY:"12345"

config file
import os
headers = {"headers": os.environ.get("KEY")}
```